# spring @autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

to use @autowired. in xml, i only need to included

`<context:annotation-config />`    ?

is there any other tag i need to put ? need to put **componenet-scan** ?

weird, i get error below

```
ERROR - ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(203) | Context initialization fa
iled
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcess
or': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.bean
s.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'order' of bean class [org.springfr
amework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor]: No proper
ty 'order' found
Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'order' of
bean class [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanP
ostProcessor]: No property 'order' found
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrap
perImpl.java:376)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:861)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<context:annotation-config />` option was introduced in Spring 2.5. Under the covers, this creates and configures a `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, and uses the `order` property of that. In Spring 2.0, `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` exists, but has no `order` property.

My guess is that you have both Spring 2.5 and 2.0 on your classpath. The copy of 2.5 would have allowed you to use `<context:annotation-config />`, but then it used the 2.0 copy for `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.

Comment: Probably should use 3.0.x regardless.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a class path issue. Do you mix incompatible versions of different Spring jars, or are there multiple `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` classes on your classpath?

Earlier versions of that class (up to 2.0.x) did not have an order property.